# Why Xnest server has different glxinfo than normal Xorg server?

Tags: xorg, x11

I've run Xnest server. It appears Xnest doesn't use my graphic card or at least it doesn't use direct rendering.

Normal Xorg `glxinfo`

```
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 8.0.3
```

Xnest Xorg `glxinfo`

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 8.0.3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XNest is a "Virtual" X Server, it runs on top of the existing server. Just like with virtual machines, the emulated or "virtual" device is often a generic virtual device. Being generic and virtual they use their own set of drivers, etc.
So basically it shows differently because it is a virtual copy of the actual window server.

Comment: That's ok, but why there is also difference between OpenGL versions?

Comment: Different drivers.  The VMWare, Inc driver evidently hasn't been updated in a bit.